# Unix - Sorting file name with a key but not knowing its position

Tags: sorting, unix, filenames

I would like to sort those files using Unix commands:

```
MyFile_fdfdsf_20140326.txt
MyFile_4fg5d6_20100301.csv
MyFile_dfgfdklm_19990101.tar.gz
```

The result I am waiting for here is `MyFile_fdfdsf_20140326.txt`

So I'd like to get the file with the newest date.

I can't use 'sort -k', as the position of the key (the date) may vary 
But in my file name there are always two "_" delimiters and a dot '.' for the file extension

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Is the date always after the second `_`?

Comment: Thank you for you answer. It's perfect.

But out of curiosity, what if I had an unknown number of "\_" delimiters, but that the date was always after the last "\_" delimiter.

MyFile_abc_def_..._20140326.txt

sort -t'_' -nk??? file

Answer (score 0):

Then use `-t` to indicate the field separator and set it to `_`:

```
sort -t'_' -k3
```

See an example of sorting the file names if they are in a file. I used `-n` for numeric sort and `-r` for reverse order:

```
$ sort -t'_' -nk3 file
MyFile_dfgfdklm_19990101.tar.gz
MyFile_4fg5d6_20100301.csv
MyFile_fdfdsf_20140326.txt

$ sort -t'_' -rnk3 file
MyFile_fdfdsf_20140326.txt
MyFile_4fg5d6_20100301.csv
MyFile_dfgfdklm_19990101.tar.gz
```

---

From `man sort`:

> **-t**, --field-separator=SEP
>
> use SEP instead of non-blank to blank transition
>
> **-n**, --numeric-sort
>
> compare according to string numerical value
>
> **-r**, --reverse
>
> reverse the result of comparisons

## Update

> Thank you for you answer. It's perfect. But out of curiosity, what if
>   I had an unknown number of delimiters, but the date was always after
>   the last "_" delimiter. MyFile_abc_def_...*20140326.txt sort -t'*'
>   -nk??? file –  user3464809

You can trick it a little bit: print the last field, sort and then remove it.

```
awk -F_ '{print $NF, $0}' a | sort | cut -d'_' -f2-
```

See an example:

```
$ cat a
MyFile_fdfdsf_20140326.txt
MyFile_4fg5d6_20100301.csv
MyFile_dfgfdklm_19990101.tar.gz
MyFile_dfgfdklm_asdf_asdfsadfas_19940101.tar.gz
MyFile_dfgfdklm_asdf_asdfsadfas_29990101.tar.gz

$ awk -F_ '{print $NF, $0}' a | sort | cut -d'_' -f2-
dfgfdklm_asdf_asdfsadfas_19940101.tar.gz
dfgfdklm_19990101.tar.gz
4fg5d6_20100301.csv
fdfdsf_20140326.txt
dfgfdklm_asdf_asdfsadfas_29990101.tar.gz
```

Comment: But the OP is saying that each file may have the date in a different position within the name (although he did a bad job of demonstrating that possibility in his example).

Comment: Apparently it was fine, see comments on the question. But thanks for letting me know, @dg99